# Class has colliding constructor definitions coming from traits

Tags: php, class, traits

having a bit of a strange problem. I keep on getting this error

`UploadPicture has colliding constructor definitions coming from traits`

But none of my traits have constructors and neither does my UploadPicture class

Not sure if it could be these at the top of my `PictureTrait`?

```
use Imagine\Image\Box;
use Imagine\Image\ImageInterface;
use Orchestra\Imagine\Facade;
```

Pastebin of files

[UploadPicture.php](http://pastebin.com/DE0FR4xe)

[PictureTrait.php](http://pastebin.com/CDX9N2HL)

Comment: Does this happen when `use PictureTrait, UploadTrait, PublishableTrait;` is uncommented or commented?

Comment: No, I have removed UploadTrait, and PublishableTrait but it happens with PictureTrait so my guess is the problem lies within that file

Comment: I mean yes it does, I was commenting them out to find out where the error lies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The class was called `UploadPicture` but I have a function inside PictureTrait called `uploadPicture`, changing the function name has fixed it.